# Смена контента при клике jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Есть массив php в который занесен контент

```
$arendaDropDown = array(
     'web' => array(
         'title' => 'Тариф “WEB”',
         'subtitle' => 'Идеальное предложение для небольших компаний, рассчитанное на одно или два бухгалтерских места. Если вам необходимо простое и в то же время недорогое решение, то пакет Web — ваш выбор. Доступ к приложению вы получаете через привычный web-браузер.',
         'list' => array(
             1 => 'Аренда 1С любой конфигурации из списка доступных',
             2 => 'Техническая поддержка 24/7',
             3 => 'Обновление одной типовой базы 1С бесплатно',
             4 => 'Ежедневное резервное копирование с глубиной хранения 7 дней',
             5 => 'Печать документов из облака на принтере',
             6 => '2 Гб свободного дискового пространства на одного пользователя'
         ),
         'bottomText' => ''
     ),
     'busines' => array(
         'title' => 'Тариф “Бизнес”',
         'subtitle' => 'Оптимальное предложение как для представителей малого, так и среднего бизнеса. Удобное решение для 5-10 пользователей. Доступ к конфигурациям 1С предоставляется через удаленный рабочий стол.',
         'list' => array(
             1 => 'Аренда 1С любой конфигурации',
             2 => 'Техническая поддержка 24/7',
             3 => 'Обновление одной типовой базы 1С бесплатно',
             4 => 'Ежедневное резервное копирование с глубиной хранения 7 дней',
             5 => 'Печать документов из облака на принтере',
             6 => '3 Гб свободного дискового пространства на одного пользователя'
         ),
         'bottomText' => ''
     ),
     'corporotiv' => array(
         'title' => 'Тариф “Корпоративный”',
         'subtitle' => 'Удачное решение для компаний с большим документооборотом и более чем с 10 пользователями. При аренде сервера вы получаете не только установленные продукты 1С. На сервер можно установить дополнительное ПО и отправлять отчетность или использовать браузер для доступа к интернету. ',
         'list' => array(
             1 => 'Аренда 1С любой конфигурации',
             2 => 'Техническая поддержка 24/7',
             3 => 'Обновление одной типовой базы 1С бесплатно',
             4 => 'Ежедневное резервное копирование с глубиной хранения 7 дней',
             5 => 'Печать документов из облака на принтере',
             6 => 'Необходимое свободное дисковое пространство на одного пользователя'
         ),
         'bottomText' => 'Доступ к приложениям 1С предоставляется как через RDP (удаленный рабочий стол), так и через web-браузер.'
     )
 );
```

HTML

```
<div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud container ww960">
        <div class="arenda-1c-blue-title">Больше не нужен сервер - арендуйте 1С в облаке!</div>
        <div class="arenda-1c-subtitle">Работайте в 1С онлайн через любой браузер или удаленный рабочий стол. Выбирайте нужную конфигурацию и получите доступ к рабочему приложению уже через 10 минут (при подключении пакетов Web или "Бизнес")!</div>
        <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-cases col-md-4">
            <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case">
                <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-wrapper">
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-title">web</div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-subtitle">Доступ к 1С через браузер</div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Подключение через <span>браузер</span></span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>До 3-х баз 1С</span></span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>Обновление 1С</span> бесплатно</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>2GB SSD</span> дискового пространствана пользователя</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Ежедневное резервное копирование </span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Техническая поддержка 24/7</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-price">700 <span>₽</span><span class="mounth">Месяц</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-button">
                        <div class="landing-button">Тестировать бесплатно</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-more-about-tariff"><span class="more-tariff-info-button" data-name-tariff="web">Подробнее о тарифе</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-cases col-md-4">
            <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case">
                <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-wrapper">
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-title">бизнес</div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-subtitle">Доступ к 1С через WEB или RDP</div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Подключение через <span>Web/RDP</span></span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>До 3-х баз 1С</span></span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>Обновление 1С</span> бесплатно</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>2GB SSD</span> дискового пространствана пользователя</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Ежедневное резервное копирование </span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Техническая поддержка 24/7</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-price">1000 <span>₽</span><span class="mounth">Месяц</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-button">
                        <div class="landing-button">Тестировать бесплатно</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-more-about-tariff"><span class="more-tariff-info-button" data-name-tariff="busines">Подробнее о тарифе</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-cases col-md-4">
            <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case">
                <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-wrapper">
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-title">корпоративный</div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-subtitle">Аренда сервера 1С (Web или RDP)</div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Подключение через <span>браузер</span></span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>До 3-х баз 1С</span></span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>Обновление 1С</span> бесплатно</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text"><span>2GB SSD</span> дискового пространствана пользователя</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Ежедневное резервное копирование </span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-list-item"><span class="check">✔</span><span class="text">Техническая поддержка 24/7</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-price">от 1000 <span>₽</span><span class="mounth">Месяц</span></div>
                    <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-button">
                        <div class="landing-button">Тестировать бесплатно</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="arenda-1c-in-cloud-case-more-about-tariff"><span class="more-tariff-info-button" data-name-tariff="corporotiv">Подробнее о тарифе</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="replace-block-content col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="replace-block-content-title">title</div>
            <div class="replace-block-content-subtitle">subtitle</div>
            <div class="replace-block-content-list col-md-12">
                <div class="replace-block-content-image col-md-5">image</div>
                <div class="replace-block-content-list-text col-md-7">text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Как сделать что бы при клике на определенный кейс, подставлялся нужный контент из массива? Заранее спасибо[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var objFromPhp = arenda1cDropDownItemsContent;
    $('.more-tariff-info-button').click(function(){
         var curTariffName = $(this).attr('data-name-tariff');

       if($(this).attr('data-click') == 'false'){          
           $(this).attr('data-click', 'true');
           $('.more-tariff-info-button').not(this).attr('data-click', false);
           replaceContent(this,objFromPhp[curTariffName], 'show');
       }
       else{
           $(this).attr('data-click', 'false');
           replaceContent(this, objFromPhp[curTariffName], 'hide');
       }


    });
});

function replaceContent(source_obj, obj, flag){
    console.log(obj, flag);
}
```

Comment: Вместо чего он должен вставляться?

Comment: @Manitikyl Нужно чтобы контент подставлялся в блок ниже, под каждый кейс -  свой контент. Вот пример: http://prntscr.com/k46khu

Comment: `arenda1cDropDownItemsContent` а это откуда берется? там уже есть ваш массив?